# Php Simple XML Help <gx:coord>

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, coordinates

I want to echo all "gx:coord" in a foreach.

This is what i have now:

```
# XML
$my_track = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('track.kml'));


echo $my_track->Document->description;
```

But how i get a value with gx:coord in a foreach loop?

```
<Document>
<description>Test</description>
<gx:MultiTrack>
    <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
    <gx:interpolate>1</gx:interpolate>
    <gx:Track>
        <when>2012-07-23T15:00:44.000Z</when>
        <gx:coord>2.508616 50.641113 46.0</gx:coord>
        <when>2012-07-23T15:00:44.000Z</when>
        <gx:coord>2.508616 50.641113 46.0</gx:coord>
        <when>2012-07-23T15:00:59.000Z</when>
        <gx:coord>2.508616 50.641113 49.0</gx:coord>
    </gx:Track>
    </gx:MultiTrack>
</Document>
```

I want this as result in a foreach:

```
2.508616 50.641113 46.0
2.508616 50.641113 46.0
2.508616 50.641113 49.0
```

Need realy help with this.

Comment: Are there any namespaces defined in your `kml` file...something like `xmlns:gx="..."`...you need to use that and this function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$xml = '<Document>
        <description>Test</description>
        <gx:MultiTrack>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            <gx:interpolate>1</gx:interpolate>
            <gx:Track>
                <when>2012-07-23T15:00:44.000Z</when>
                <gx:coord>2.508616 50.641113 46.0</gx:coord>
                <when>2012-07-23T15:00:44.000Z</when>
                <gx:coord>2.508616 50.641113 46.0</gx:coord>
                <when>2012-07-23T15:00:59.000Z</when>
                <gx:coord>2.508616 50.641113 49.0</gx:coord>
            </gx:Track>
            </gx:MultiTrack>
        </Document>';

$data = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
// Or $data = simplexml_load_file( $filename );

foreach ( $data -> children() -> MultiTrack -> Track -> coord as $value ) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors:

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: <gx:MultiTrack> in C:\xampp\htdocs\mytracks\informatie_track.php on line 19

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\mytracks\informatie_track.php on line 19

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: namespace error : Namespace prefix gx on interpolate is not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\mytracks\informatie_track.php on line 19

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem and I used xpath
like:

```
$arr = xpath('//gx:coord');
```

for more info look at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

and for more specified with namespace

- http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php

this will also help with what happens if you get a file without the namespace